# Solve the Bernoulli EDO $y'-y \tan x = -y^2\cos x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I bumped into this equation and I identified it as a Bernoulli EDO. I found an answer but would like to have it checked. Here is the EDO: $y'-y \tan x  = -y^2\cos x$

Comment: What did you get?

Comment: $y=\frac{1}{\cos x (x-c)}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dividing both sides of the equation by $y^{-2}$ you have $y^{-2}y'-\tan x y^{-1}=-\cos x$ and using the change of variables $u=y^{-1}$ ($\Rightarrow u'=-y^{-2}y'$) you get a linear equation in $u$: $u'+(\tan x) u=\cos x$ with integrating factor $\mu(x)=\sec x$. I think you can complete the rest...

Comment: How did you pick that integrating factor? I fail to see how the product rule on the left hand side is taken care off

Comment: I edit my answer the integrating factor must be $\sec x=\frac{1}{\cos x}$.

Comment: YES, that makes sense. It's a great DFQ problem to be kept in my file for future students.